# Adding a full width image to Google Doc's footer using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I recently watched a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRo8SVt-HJM) demonstrating how to create a letterhead by inserting text and images in the header of a Google Docs document using Google Apps Script. I've successfully implemented this for the header, but now I'd like to add an image to the footer. The requirements are as follows:

1. The image in the footer should be full width with no margin.
2. The image's width should automatically adjust to fit both Portrait and Landscape documents.

[image]
Additionally, I have another Google Docs template with a full-width image in the footer that its Text Wrapping is set up as Behind Text, and I'm wondering if it's possible to copy the footer section from that document and insert it into my current document if Apps Script functions are limited.

How can I achieve this using Google Apps Script or any other method that might work? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. In your situation, is "Different first page" checked or unchecked? 2. Can you provide your current script? 3. Is `Additionally, I have another Google Docs template with a full-width image in the footer that its Text Wrapping is set up as Behind Text, and I'm wondering if it's possible to copy the footer section from that document` your 3rd question?